# I am having trouble solving a math problem with while-loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The math problem says:
Write a program in which you can insert a positive number from 1 to 100. When a number outside the range is inserted, there should be an error message and another number should be inserted.

This is the code I tried:

```js
function solve(input) {
  let number = (input.shift());

  while (number < 1 || number > 100) {
    console.log('Invalid number.');
    number = Number(input.shift());
  }
  
  console.log(`The number is: ${number}`)
}

solve(['35', '105', '0', '-200', '77'])
```

The end result should be:

```
35
The number is: 35
105
Invalid number!
0
Invalid number!
-200
Invalid number!
77
The number is: 77
```

Comment: Currently it only console.logs The number is: 35 and that's it.

Comment: Because the condition `number < 1 || number > 100` fails for first number itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to take all values and check for `undefined`.

```js
function solve(input) {
    let number = input.shift();

    while (number !== undefined) {
        if (number < 1 || number > 100) {
            console.log('Invalid number.');
        } else {
            console.log(`The number is: ${number}`)
        }
        number = input.shift();
    }
}

solve(['35', '105', '0', '-200', '77'])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. Can you please tell me how to take the values and check for undefined? How do I do that?

Comment: please see above. `number !== undefined` checks if the value is not `undefined`. `shift` returns `undefined` for not existend values in the array (it could be `undefined` as value in the array, as for sparse items, which are not given here).

Answer (score 0):

> Currently it only console.logs The number is: 35 and that's it. ?

It's printing only once because the `number < 1 || number > 100` condition fails on first number itself,

---

Instead what you can do simply is, initialize a `counter` with value equal to `input.length-1`, check for value at respective index from `input`, if that is out of the range show invalid, else just print the number, decrement the counter by `1` each time at end of loop

```js
function solve(input) {
  let i = input.length - 1
  while (i >= 0) {
    if (input[i] < 1 || input[i] > 100) {
      console.log('Invalid number.', `The number is: ${input[i]}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`The number is: ${input[i]}`)
    }
    i--
  }
}
solve(['35', '105', '0', '-200', '77'])
```